# Unable to use downloaded image using the Nokia imaging SDK

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

Nokia just released 'Nokia Imaging SDK' version 1. However, now I can not use a Stream download image since SDK's StreamImageSource tries to use Stream.Length which is unavailable for Async Stream. How can I get around this issue?

Here is my code:

```
HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
Stream orgImageStream = await c.GetStreamAsync(imageUri);
var imageSource = new StreamImageSource(orgImageStream);  //fails here since he tries to use Stream.Length
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting bug - it would be useful to report it to Nokia.
Anyway, you can solve it by either saving the file to isolated storage first, or copying it to **MemoryStream** locally:

```
HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
Stream orgImageStream = await c.GetStreamAsync(imageUri);

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
await orgImageStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var imageSource = new StreamImageSource(ms);
```

But don't forget to use all Streams in **using (Stream ... ) { ... }** to Dispose them properly!

Comment: After some late night coding I figured out a similar approach. I cast the Stream to a byte[] and pass it to a MemoryStream to feed StreamImageSource. I haven't tried your approach, but I will mark it as answered. Thanks Martin

Comment: Note that since the stream data is now in fact loaded in memory, you can avoid some overhead by using BufferImageSource instead.